# Importing JSON data into SQL Server; losing decimal precision and scale

Tags: json, sql-server, data-import

I'm importing an array of JSON documents, like the following:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6092e24247f3024d478902c2"
  },
  "startSearch": "2021-05-05T18:20:50.132Z",
  "Inst_ID": 856,
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "searchpath": "/Account/Main/_LookupOptimize",
  "Params": {
    "AccountStatusDisplay": [
      "Active",
      "Out For Repo",
      "Repossessed"
    ]
  },
  "endSearch": "2021-05-05T18:20:53.993Z",
  "elapsedTime": 3.861,
  "totalRecordsFound": 1988
}
```

I'm importing them into a local instance of SQL Server 2019 like so:

```
Declare @JSON nvarchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\QueueSearch.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import

INSERT INTO myJSON
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH 
(
    [_id] nvarchar(max),
    [startSearch] datetime,
    [Inst_ID] int,
    [hostname] nvarchar(80),
    [searchpath] nvarchar(50),
    [Params] nvarchar(max),
    [endSearch] datetime,
    [elapsedTime] NUMERIC(10,4),
    [totalRecordsFound] int
)
```

My problem is that the elapsedTime values are being rounded off to integers. (The _id values aren't getting imported either, but first things first.) I'm probably missing something really simple, but how can I preserve the accuracy of my elapsedTime values? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That `openjson()` code looks fine, except for missing `[Params] nvarchar(max) as json`. So what's the definition of the `myJSON` table?

Comment: I suspect that your table has elapsedTime defined as an integer. Your select without the insert returns the correct value

Comment: You probably also want either `[_id] nvarchar(max) '$._id."$oid"` or `[_id] nvarchar(max) as json`

Answer (score 0):

Verify the data type of elapsedTime is `numeric(10,4)` and explicitly map the columns in INSERT to make sure that you're inserting `elapsedTime` from the JSON into the `elapsedTime` column.

```
INSERT INTO myJSON([_id],startSearch,Inst_ID,hostname,searchpath,Params,endSearch,elapsedTime,totalRecordsFound)
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH 
(
    [_id] nvarchar(max),
    [startSearch] datetime,
    [Inst_ID] int,
    [hostname] nvarchar(80),
    [searchpath] nvarchar(50),
    [Params] nvarchar(max),
    [endSearch] datetime,
    [elapsedTime] NUMERIC(10,4),
    [totalRecordsFound] int
)
```

Comment: Thanks @David! Turns out my destination table had the column set for decimal(18,0). <facepalm> I'm still wondering what is happening to the _id and Params columns, though; they are JSON subdocuments in the source, but the destination columns are NULL.